# Foreach loop with two lists for corresponding rows (perl)

Tags: perl

I would like some help in what it seems to be a simple issue in a `perl script`.

I have two lists as follows. Both have the same amount of rows, and the first row of list1 corresponds to the first row of list2 and so on.

list1

```
car
ball
```

list2

```
30
40
```

I want to write a `perl` script to run programs that calls files with names starting with rows of list1. In one of these programs, I have to consider the content of list2, but doing this only for the correspondent row in list1.

This is what I have tried:

`perl test.pl list1 list2`

test.pl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $lib = $ARGV[0];
my $cov = $ARGV[1];

chomp $lib;
chomp $cov;

open(INPUT, "$lib");
my @lib = <INPUT>;
close(INPUT);

foreach my $i (@lib){
        chomp ($i);

        `samtools fasta $i\.sorted.bam > $i\.fasta`;
        `jellyfish count -m 80 -L $cov -s 275M -t 10 -C -o $i\.jf $i\.fasta`;
        `jellyfish histo $i\.jf > $i\.histo`;


}
```

The first program (`samtools`) is executed correctly, but the second is not because it can't read what is inside variable `$cov`.

In other words, I would like that option -L from `jellyfish count` be "30" for "car" and "40" for "ball", but I couldn't make it.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't make it clear. I would like that option -L from jellyfish count be "30" for "car" and "40" for "ball"

Comment: You were storing `list1` content in `@lib` and where you're storing `list2` contents? How it will determine `list2` content in `$cov`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
my ($file1, $file2) = ($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]);

my @file1_lines = read_file($file1);
my @file2_lines = read_file($file2);

if ($#file1_lines == $#file2_lines) {
    foreach my $element (0..$#file1_lines){
        my $lib = $file1_lines[$element]; chomp $lib;
        my $cov = $file2_lines[$element]; chomp $cov;
        
        print "samtools fasta ".$lib."\.sorted.bam > ".$lib."\.fasta\n";
        print "jellyfish count -m 80 -L ".$cov." -s 275M -t 10 -C -o ".$lib."\.jf ".$lib."\.fasta\n";
        print "jellyfish histo ".$lib."\.jf > ".$lib."\.histo\n";
    }
} else {
    print "$file1 and $file2 doesn't have same number of lines\n";
}
```

Here I have used [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp) to read entire content of the file into an array. So you must have `File::Slurp` Perl module in your environment.

Both the file contents are being stored in a two different arrays called `@file1_lines` and `@file2_lines` respectively.